# Rails Strong Parameters Merging or Conditional Strong Parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters, cancancan, sanitization

Based on a users authorization, I'd like to sanitize the parameters to include the ones which they are allowed to update. There are 5 different roles for the one model, and I'd rather not list out 25 possible combinations and call

params.require(:asset).permit( stuff )

25 times

Is there a way to "build" the strong parameters? The only possible way I've found is "merge" but I can't seem to get it to work

This is where I'm at:

```
def update_params
    p = params.require(:asset)
    if can? :update, Asset
      p.merge params.require(:asset).permit(:code, :description)
    end
    if can? :update, Ability::THING1
      p.merge params.require(:asset).permit(:some_nested_stuff => [:id, :quantity, :_destroy],
                   :some_other_nested_stuff => [:id, :quantity, :_destroy])
    end
    if can? :update, Ability::THING2
      p.merge params.require(:asset).permit(more_nested_stuff: [:id, :date, :note])
    end
    if can? :update, AssetNote
      p.merge params.require(:asset).permit(notes_attributes: [:id, :note, :_destroy])
    end
    p
  end
```

With this I get "ForbiddenAttributesError" instead of it just throwing away the attributes.

Answer (score 2):

Merge is the way to go as far as I know. On the other hand, your merge is not working because `.merge` does not update the hash `p`, you can either do `p = p.merge` or use `p.merge!` which does modify `p`.

Also, depending on how nested your models are you might need `.deep_merge` instead of `merge`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Cheers. I realised that right after I posted the question and made the change, but am still having no love :( Same error

Also tried deep_merge!

Comment: Do you have the corresponding `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in your models?

Comment: Yeah, all works fine before adding any of this sanitization in. It used to be just one big params.require(blah).permit(lots_of_blah)

Comment: It seems to be working after building an array and passing that to permit. I'm not sure if this is a best practice solution or not

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this solution is working - just building an array and passing that to permit. I have no idea if this would be considered best practice

```
def update_params
    a = []
    if can? :update, Asset
      a += [:code, :description]
    end
    if can? :update, Ability::THING1
      a += [:some_nested_stuff => [:id, :quantity, :_destroy],
                   :some_other_nested_stuff => [:id, :quantity, :_destroy]]
    end
    ......
    params.require(:asset).permit(a)
  end
```

Comment: Just curious, does the resulting hash look like the one generated with `merge`?

Comment: I didn't check. Maybe I was calling merge with the wrong arguments which could be why it didn't work?

Comment: Yeah, definitely possible. That might have caused the ForbiddenAttributesError error. Anyways, glad you found a way to get it to work.